# RTK Query: Specifying error type per endpoint

Tags: typescript, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

Is there a way to specify error response per endpoint? Like we can specify Result & Request type when defining a query or mutation. I did went through the documentation and updated the base query. I am getting the generic success/error response types but still trying to figure out how to define error type per endpoint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per our [GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/1591) (which might be insightful for others with the same question): not at the moment.

Comment: thanks a lot for the detailed reply on github.

Comment: @phry can we specify an error type for all APIs in one place?

Comment: That error will depend on the `baseQuery` you use - if it's a `fetchBaseQuery`, it will be an according fetch-typed error.
By the way: you should probably only have one API in your application, not multiple!

Answer (score 0):

My issue as well is that there is a type definition for {error} and they don't comply to my console.log(error). The following solution allowed me to define my own types for {error}

```
} else if (error) {
    console.log(error);
    const newError:CreateYourInterfaceBasedOnConsoleLog = error;
    content = <p>{newError.status} = {newError.data.detail}</p>
} else {
```